# Rails collection_select not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I have a very simple rails app to ask questions. Three Models Question, User, Teacher. Questions belong_to User and Teacher. User and Teacher has_many Questions.

I am trying to have a drop down of users and teachers to select in the Questions _form.html.erb file.

I have this collection_select and it displays fine but it will not save user id in the Questions user_id field.

```
<%= collection_select(:question, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=>true}) %>
                       1.         2.       3.         4.   5.       6.
```

1. The model
2. input
3. collect of users
4. what will be saved
5. what is displayed
6. prompt with "please select"

Please tell me what I am doing wrong to save the user.id to the question.user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems fine with your view. Your problem could be in controller or model, depending on your Rails version.

## My first guess

In Rails 3:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
```

In Rails 4:

```
class QuestionsController <  ApplicationController
  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:user_id)
  end
```

## Second guess

You are posting to an incorrect route.

Comment: This worked thank you I forgot to add :user_id to questions params